# MS SQL Update with .WRITE doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a problem with an update command on `MS SQL Server`. If I use `.WRITE`, the command doesn't, even the estimated execution plan cannot be generated.

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Blob
(
  BlobData VARBINARY(MAX) NULL
  , BlobId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Blob] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (
    [BlobId] ASC
  )
)
```

And this this is SQL update:

```
UPDATE dbo.Blob SET BlobData.WRITE(@Data, NULL, NULL) WHERE BlobId = @Id
```

And for this update, the execution plan cannot be generated.
We have read [this article](http://maginaumova.com/update-with-write-on-varcharmax-column-time-outs/), used the suggestions, but it didn't solve the problem.

The customer uses `MS SQL Server 2008R2 SP2`.
We couldn't reproduce it on our `sql servers (on the same version)`.

Do have any idea what could cause this? Or any idea where to search for the solution.

**Update:** No error message, just the script (plan generation) running for eternity (or until i stop it manually).

**Update2:** Without the `.WRITE`, the command works perfectly.

Comment: First of all provided script is incorrect. Then post the actual error text that  you have got. :)

Comment: And during simple select it gives you clustered index seek in plan without any problem?

Comment: Thank you @rudym, i accepted the suggestions. And sorry, this is my first post.
About the error: No error message, the plan generation running for eternity.

Comment: @rudym Yes, select finished immediately and the plan is simple clustered index seek.

Comment: and `UPDATE dbo.Blob SET BlobData = 123456 WHERE BlobId = 1` runs too? And you sure that there is no blocking of that row during update process?

Comment: "just the script (plan generation) running for eternity" - check what this query is waiting for in sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks

Comment: @rudym Yes, it executed prompt without delay or error. If the `.WRITE` is in the `update`, it doesn't work.
Even if run this: `IF(1=2) UPDATE dbo.Blob SET BlobData.WRITE(@Data, NULL, NULL) WHERE BlobId = -1`

Comment: strange behavior. Is it working this way `BlobData.WRITE(123, NULL, NULL)`  or `BlobData.WRITE(123, 0, 3)` ?

Comment: Have you checked disk related problems of trying to store big blob data. How much of empty space have you there? And I hope you are making your tests there exactly the way you are doing it here? On freshly created empty table Blob?

Comment: There is no space problem, the UPDATE is working without .WRITE. We modified a stored procedure and it stopped everything in the database when we executed it. So we started to investigate and then we found this strange behavior. In our, and other systems of our clients this problem is not exists.

Comment: New information: if we turn `OFF` the `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` it is working, if we turn it `ON` it is not working.

Comment: Good to know. You need to turn it off despite on the table you are updating? Again, do you make tests on new empty table?

Comment: We have a possible solution, tomorrow we are going to test it:
Step 1: ALTER DATABASE Test SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS OFF
Step 2: Create a dummy statistics: CREATE STATISTICS stats_BlobData ON dbo.Blob (BlobData) WITH SAMPLE 0 ROWS, NORECOMPUTE 
Step 3: ALTER DATABASE Test SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the final solution:
Step 1: `ALTER DATABASE Test SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS OFF` 
Step 2: Create a dummy statistics: `CREATE STATISTICS stats_BlobData ON dbo.Blob (BlobData) WITH SAMPLE 0 ROWS, NORECOMPUTE` 
Step 3: `ALTER DATABASE Test SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON`